# Spring MVC no setter found for property 'xxxx' in class 'xxxx'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting four 'no setter found for property 'xxxx' in class com.rusapp.batch.trans.OLFMWriter'. A fifth bean in that class does not have an error, inputQueue. The rest have errors in the xml below at each of the property lines.

The beans appear as such:

```
<bean id="inputQueue" class="com.rusapp.batch.trans.OLFMWriter">
    <property name="inputQueue" value="${${ENV}_MQ_FM_INPUT_QUEUE}" />
</bean>

<bean id="replyQueue" class="com.rusapp.batch.trans.OLFMWriter">
    <property name="replyQueue" value="${${ENV}_MQ_FM_REPLY_QUEUE}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.rusapp.batch.trans.OLFMWriter">
    <property name="mqConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnection" />
</bean>

<bean id="JMSDestination"
    class="com.rusapp.batch.trans.OLFMWriter">
    <property name="JMSDestination" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
</bean>

<bean id="JMSReplyTo"
    class="com.rusapp.batch.trans.OLFMWriter">
    <property name="JMSReplyTo" ref="jmsDestinationResolverReceiver" />
</bean>
```

The setters in the class appear as follows:

```
public static void setMqConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory _mqConnectionFactory) {
    OLFMWriter._mqConnectionFactory = _mqConnectionFactory;
}
public static void setReplyQueue(String _replyQueue) {
    OLFMWriter._replyQueue = _replyQueue;
}
public static void setJMSDestination(Destination _JMSDestination) {
    OLFMWriter._JMSDestination = _JMSDestination;
}
public static void setJMSReplyTo(Destination _JMSReplyTo) {
    OLFMWriter._JMSReplyTo = _JMSReplyTo;
}
public void setInputQueue(String inputQueue){
    _inputQueue = inputQueue;
}
```

This is not my code and I'm not too knowledgeable with Spring yet but I can't find anything wrong with the setter names. I thought it was a workspace error but they have persisted through several restarts of Eclipse.

Can anyone find any obvious faults with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setters are static which means that they don't conform to the java beans specification.

I think you'll want to use a [MethodInvokingFactorybean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) instead.

```
<bean abstract="true" id="abstractParent" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.rusapp.batch.trans.OLFMWriter"/>
</bean>
<bean id="inputQueue" parent="abstractParent">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="setInputQueue" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list><value>${${ENV}_MQ_FM_INPUT_QUEUE}</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="replyQueue" parent="abstractParent">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="setReplyQueue" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list><value>${${ENV}_MQ_FM_REPLY_QUEUE}</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
etc...
```

Comment: Yep, that was the source of the warnings. For whatever reason they don't show as errors in my friend's workspace. However, it deployed and ran regardless, though we now have best practice code. Thanks

Comment: "For whatever reason they don't show as errors in my friend's workspace" - guessing it's logging configuration

Comment: You can also keep the same Spring context and have static variables and non-static setter methods that set the static variable: public void setJMSReplyTo(Destination dest){OLFMWriter._JMSReplyTo = dest;}